# Difference between let and allow in a rspec test. Do both stub?

Tags: rspec

I have this method that I'm trying to test:

```
def build
    return if !cookies["__utmz"] && !cookies["__utma"]
    binding.pry
    @data = GaCookieParser::GaCookieParser.new(
      utmz: cookies["__utmz"],
      utma: cookies["__utma"]
    )
    build_utmz
    build_utma
    TrafficSource.new(params)
  end
```

This is my test:

```
context 'when cookies have necessary params' do
      let(:cookies) { complete_cookies }
      let(:complete_cookies) do
        {
          '__utmz' => 'something',
          '__utma' => 'something'
        }
      end
```

I used a let and when I hit the binding, "cookies" does indeed return me complete_cookies.

let is only supposed to "stub" the method inside the test right whereas allow will stub the method anywhere in the actual code right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` and `allow` do extremely different things. `let` is not a method stub... it's a way of creating test data/objects to manipulate in your tests.

a `let` is a nicer way of doing something like:

```
before do
   @cookies =  { '__utmz' => 'something', '__utma' => 'something' }
end
```

then having to use `@cookies` in your tests.
It's better than instantiating things in before-blocks because it isn't instantiated until you actually use it - which reduces instantiation of objects that aren't used in all tests.

If you really want to stub a method, you must use a `receives` expectation eg:

```
allow(thing).to receive(:cookies).and_return(complete_cookies)
expect(thing).to receive(:cookies).and_return(complete_cookies)
```

The behaviour you're seeing is, I think, not what you're expecting... because what you've accidentally done is paper over the method `cookies` with a local variable called `cookies`...

Which is a bit dangerous and likely to be brittle.
In this instance, I'd use an actual `expect` or `allow` on the object that contains the `build` method (which you haven't named in your example code above). That is the standard practice for what you seem to want to do.
In that case, yes it will indeed stub over the method, as you expect it to.

Comment: Can you use 'allow' and expect interchangably? I thought allow was for stubbing and 'expect' was for testing that an object actually receives a method. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs

Comment: @Jwan622 You are right `allow` creates a stub while `expect` creates a mock. You will need to decide yourself which one suits your needs better. Here is a discussion on the matter [RSpec allow/expect vs just expect/and_return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006913/rspec-allow-expect-vs-just-expect-and-return) and here is discussion on let [When to use rspec let()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359558/when-to-use-rspec-let)

Comment: Yes, you can't use them interchangably - use the one appropriate... however they are both closely related things (you are papering over a method and returning a value of your choosing), whereas a `let` is a very different thing to either.